# Removing the white dots from lightdm on 15.04

Tags: lightdm, 15.04

I have tried the approach that I have used before on earlier releases of Ubuntu but on 15.04 I have found that the following commands are not working.

```
sudo xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm

sudo su lightdm -s /bin/bash

gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-grid false
```

When I run the last command I get the following:

```
(process:5354): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=1af246dec6324e1ca014e1c3c06da71c --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1
```

Can anybody suggest what I'm doing wrong, or ways that I could diagnose what is failing?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install **Ubuntu Tweak**. It still works although it hasn't been updated for a while. You can download the deb package from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak
2. Start **Ubuntu Tweak**, go to **Tweaks** > **Startup** > **Login Settings**. There you should be able to "*Unlock*" Root privileges and select some *LDM Preferences* like "**Draw Grid**".

[image]

Comment: COmmand line is good but GUI is easier and has done the trick.

Comment: What GTK theme are you using?

Comment: @Waldir Leoncio, it's Vertex Light

Answer (score -1):

According to the (German) [Wiki of ubuntuusers.de](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/LightDM#Konfiguration), starting from Ubuntu 12.04 you need to use the `dconf-editor` GUI tool. You start it just as you did with `gsettings set` before: Giv the 'lightdm' user account access to your GUI (`xhost`), switch to that user account (`su`) and start `dconf-editor`

```
xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
sudo su lightdm -s /bin/bash
dconf-editor
```

Comment: this results in the error that prompted the question